# Creating installer for ATL Dll

Tags: dll, com, mfc, activex, atl

I have created a ATL Dll to be invoked by the javascript code based on this [advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9322137/implementing-activex-control-for-web-browser)

Now i need to create a setup project and signing it with digital certificate. I used the utility makecab.exe with the following command

makecab e:\sample.dll test.cab

the output is a cab file in zip format with only the dll packed into it. Is this sufficient? should i create inf files for registering it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a .INF file within the cabinet. For a complete description, see full article here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa751974(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The Microsoft Cabinet developent kit is no longer available http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310618. what should i use?